# Start codon and 5' codon

Tags: dna, amino-acids, mhc

[Here](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ipd/imgt/hla/alignment/help/) it says:

> For [amino acid-based systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid), the start codon of the mature protein is
> labeled codon 1. The codon 5' to this is numbered -1.

So, I assumed the [START codon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Start_codon) is either -1 or 0.

But, when I align sequences on the HLA-A gene, both amino acids at positions -1 and 0, aren't a [methionine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methionine) which I thought was the only start codon possible.
[image]

There is however a Methionine at position -24.

Am I missing something? What are these amino acids numbered from -24 to 0. I've heard it's the "[signal peptide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_peptide)", but cannot find any source about it, and I'm confused about the help page of this website. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Beware, the manual says _the start codon of the **mature protein** is labeled codon 1_. Proteins undergo post-translational modifications and processing during which chemical modifications or protein cleavages happen. HLA-A has a signal peptide (see [UniProt](https://www.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/B1PKZ1/entry#ptm_processing)) which is 24 aa long. The term **mature protein** denotes the protein after processing, namely after the removal of [signal peptide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_peptide).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So is the **start codon of the mature protein** not necessarily a Methionine?

Comment: Correct. Protein is synthesized in its nascent form with methionine as the first amino acid. Later, the signal peptide is cleaved away, and therefore some other amino acid becomes the first one in the mature protein.

Comment: I understand, so almost all proteins are synthesized in their nascent form with methionine as their first amino acid but some have a signal peptide that is later cleaved away?